# Can I manage suppliers SLA's by using entitlements?

Tags: case, relationships, entitlements

are there any use cases to demonstrate if it makes sense to manage my suppliers by using entitlements as a way to manage their SLA's, e.g., specifying agreed services, review periods, logging issues against the SLA etc.?